# \u0 characters within my app.js file when compressed

Tags: laravel

I have had this issue before when using gulp to minify javascript, I don't think I ever fixed it. However i'm getting it once again whilst using laravels setup.

Basically i'm getting strange characters within my minified app.js, as follows:

```
/* istanbul ignore else */
            if (offsetLeft < this.scrollOffset) {
                this.scrollOffset = Math.max(offsetLeft - additionalOffset, 0);
  q�SMB@_:fd�a���{<��˘�10$� onalOffset;
            }
        },
        tabProx...
```

Within the browser they are shown as dots:

[image]

This has only recently happened since putting my Laravel project within Git, so not too sure what could of changed to cause this issue.

Has anyone encountered this?

**Edit:**

Hovering over one of the dots within the console gives the a tooltip of `\u0`, if you wondering where I got that from.